# From PHP and now to Python ( Based on project needs )

Tags: php, python, ajax, notifications, polling

Basically I'm php web programmer, and I am now facing a difficulties on school project with ajax long polling (which has module with notification push). So after doing some research and read the weaknesses on doing "long-polling" with php and I found this article which is as below link:
[Simpler long polling with Django and gevent](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.gevent.org%2F2009%2F10%2F10%2Fsimpler-long-polling-with-django-and-gevent%2F)

It used pythons(gevent) together with Django library, I don't know if it was worthwhile to implement that way and then plug into my php project. If it is, where shall I start with ? Should I go through all pythons tutorial and learn Python - PHP extension ? What-else or where-else that I shall go?? 
Appreciate with all the advice given. Thanks in advance.
Eric.

Comment: What does "dunno" mean?  Also, free to drop "Okay basically" and "Thanks in advance. Eric."  None of that is meaningful.  And the non-English words are confusing.  Double punctuation marks are also silly-looking.

Comment: What's wrong with this: http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/?

Comment: @user571640: Don't apologize.  Everyone has bad English.  Just fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First.  Do a better search.

http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/

Seems to be PHP-based.  Why not use that?

> plug into my php project.

This is rarely going to be helpful.  If you have to learn Python to implement "long-polling", then you may as well stop using PHP entirely.  Django does everything PHP does (how well or how simply is not the point)

> where shall I start with ? Go through all pythons tutorial ?

All?  Hardly.  However, you'll need a Python tutorial or two before you start the DJango tutorial.

> learn Python - PHP extension ?

Only if you feel you **must** use PHP.  Django does everything PHP does, so you can stop using PHP at any time and simplify your life.

Comment: I'm doing a module which has php as the main programming language, it is impossible for me to switch it to entire different programming language.

Comment: @user571640: "it is impossible for me to switch".  False.  It may be hard to maintain, or slow to build, but it's not impossible. A "mixed" Django-PHP solution will be harder to maintain and slower to build than all PHP or all Django.  Yes, learning Python and learning Django (so you can use the preferred non-PHP long-polling) will probably be cheaper in the long run than a mixed PHP+Django site.